# LARAVEL + VUE consulta

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Buenas tardes se puede usar los controladores creados en php laravel en vue? osea las vistas en vue y los controladores en php? es posible? tengo mi archivo vue y se muestra la vista en un view llamado blade.php, o necesito crear controladores para vue?

Comment: No se entiende... podrias agragar un ejemplo?

Comment: si se puede. lo googleaste?

Comment: No se puede gente, deberia hacerlo con un api no?

Answer (score 0):

Se puede utilizando [Inertia](https://inertiajs.com/), este te permite crear aplicaciones monolíticas con Laravel (También permite user otros lenguajes backend) y usando Vue para tu ejemplo aunque también soporta otros frameworks FrontEnd.

Conozco dos maneras de hacer lo que quieres:

1. La primera sería renderizando componentes o vistas de Vue directamente desde el controlador. De esta manera es como se explica en la documentación.
2. La segunda manera te permite retornar una vista blade y dentro de esta montar los componentes de Vue.

Yo personalmente prefiero la primera. Un ejemplo para retorna un componente (Vista) de Vue directamente desde un controlador sería:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class JobController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Inertia::render('Welcome');
    }
}
```

Básicamente lo que hace Inertia::render('Welcome'); es buscar dentro de `resources/js/Pages` un archivo que se llama Welcome.vue